Deities who help to improve our mistakes?
Some people knowingly or unknowingly make mistakes in their lives even if they try to avoid them . It pains a lot when we work hard but the fruits of our anction are ruined due to some silly mistakes of which we donot get a clue beforehand and regret for it. Are their any deities who can remove this bad situations and luck from our lives and help us in our sincere efforts to improve ourselves ?

Here is how Atharva Veda 7.42.2 addresses Soma-Rudra, with hymns also found in Rig Veda 2.74 & 6.74.2 & 6.74.3:

सोमारुद्रा वि वृहतं विषूचीम् अमीवा या नो गयम् आविवेश । बाधेथां दूरं
निरृतिम् पराचैः॒ कृतं चिद् एनः प्र मुमुक्तम् अस्मत् ॥१॥ Cast away
(वृह), and separate us (विषूची) from all bondages/sicknesses (अमीवा)
from us and our families (गय) O Soma and Rudra (सोमारुद्रा ), drive
away (पराचै) afar ( दूरं) our pain/suffering (बाध) and
death/destruction (निरृति) liberate us ( मुक्त ) from those (अस्मत्)
even if (चिद्) they are committed (कृत) sins/papa ( एनः) 7.42.1
या ते रुद्र शिवा तनूरघोराऽपापकाशिनी।तया नस्तनुवा शंतमया
गिरिशन्ताभिचाकशीहि॥3.5 You (या) Rudra of Auspicious (शिवा) body (तनू),
and of fierce form (अघोरा) resident of highest place (गिरिशन्त) with
your brilliant design/thought (अभिचा +काश्) which removes our avidya
and karmic cycle of pāpa (अ-पापकाशिनी ) make us (नः) realize our
blissful clam self(शंतमया + तनू  +तया )  Svetasvatara Upaniṣhad 3.5
ते रुद्र शिवा तनूः शिवा विश्वाह भेषजी | शिवा रुद्रस्य भेषजी तया नोमृड
जीवसे 4.5.10.2 “yate Rudra Śivā tanuhu Śivā Vishvaha Bheshaji | Śivā
Rudrasya Bheshaji “ Oh Rudra you are of Śiva (auspicious) body/form.
As Śivā to your the medicine/cure (भेष॒जी) to all entirety, you are
eternal cure to all worldly ailments (विश्वाहभेषजी ) With that (तया)
auspicious form (शिवा) you are the cure to our crying/suffering
(रुद्रस्य) (samsara/avidya) medicine (भेषजी) is the relief to us all
(न) jivas (जीवसे all living entities) comfort/solace (मृड).  ~Kṛṣṇa
Yajur Veda Taittirīya Saṃhitā 4.5.1 / 4.5.10.2

Source Link with detailed explanation:
link1
link2
link3
